# Multiplicative inverse of polynomial

Tags: multiplicative-function

Question:

> Determine the multiplicative inverse of $x^2 + 1$ in $GF(2^4)$ with $$m(x) = x^4 + x + 1.$$

My confusion is over the $GF (2^4)$.

Comment: The title is misleading: in your algebraic structure there are no polynomials *as such* and thus no possible inverses of them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unclear what you're going for here, but it seems like you're talking about the 4-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb F_2$ the finite field of two elements, where $V=\mathbb F_2[X]/\langle m(X)\rangle$.

Working under that assumption, you need a polynomial $AX^3+BX^2+CX+D$ so that
$$
(X^2+1)(AX^3+BX^2+CX+D)=(X^4+X+1)p(X)+1\equiv 1\in V,
$$
where $A,B,C,D=\{0,1\}$ and $p(X)$ is some polynomial, which you can see will have degree at most $1$. You're gonna have to play around with it to come up with the answer, but this should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Here $\,{\rm GF}(2^4) \cong \Bbb F_2[x]/(x^4\!+x+1)\,$ denotes the finite field of size $\,2^4.\,$ 
We can apply the Extended Euclidean Algorithm [described here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242) over $\,\Bbb F_2\,$ to invert $\,x^2\!+1\,$ in this field

$$\begin{array}{cccc}
& x^4\!+x+1 & 1 & 0\\
& x^2\!+1   & 0 & 1\\
&x^2\!+x+1  & 1 & x^2\\
& x       & 1 & x^2\!+1\\
& 1       & x & x^3\!+x+1\\
\end{array}$$

where each row $\ a\ \ b\ \ c\ $ means that $\ a = b(x^4\!+x+1) + c(x^2\!+1).\ $ Hence, by the final row

$$ 1\, =\, x(x^4\!+x+1) + (x^3\!+x+1)(x^2\!+1)$$

which, finally, implies that $\ (x^3\!+x+1)(x^2\!+1) = 1\,$ in $\,\Bbb F_2[x]/(x^4\!+x+1).$