# gcd of two polynomials over the gf(2^4)

Tags: finite-fields, gcd-and-lcm

Can someone show me step by step of "Extended Euclidean Algorithm"
[Multiplicative inverse of polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/673385/multiplicative-inverse-of-polynomial)

> gcd of $(x^4+x+1)$ and $(x^2+1)$ over $gf(2^4)$?

what I did : 
$(x^4+x+1) = (x^2+1)(x^2-1)+(x+2)$

so do I remove the 2 ,since 2 mod 2 = 0?

$(x^2+1) = x(x)+1$?

Please show me the steps using the equation format, not the table that most people use..

Comment: So you have done the two steps necessary to show that $\gcd(x^4+x+1,x^2+1)=1$ in the ring $GF(2)[x]$. The rest goes just like when computing a modular inverse.

Comment: BTW I don't think it's quite kosher to write "over $GF(2^4)$" in this context. Your polynomials have coefficients in $GF(2)$. The GCD of two polynomials over their common field of coefficients $K$ is the same over any extension field $L$ of $K$. I do realize that this task naturally comes up, when you declare that $GF(2^4)=GF(2)[x]/\langle x^4+x+1\rangle$, and are looking for the inverse of the coset $x^2+1+\langle x^4+x+1\rangle$.